# Layer div with css shape cut-out over a div with bg color

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to indicate the active link, using a triangle-shaped CSS "cut-out" (the triangle is cut out of the white header.

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/xVvRmZ

```
/*
.container {
  width: 1200px;  
}
*/
```

How do I "cut out" the red triangle from both the **contained header** and **full-width background** (red) block? I need to cut out the triangle to expose underlying photo.

The header works great, but as soon as the full-width red block is applied to the background layer of **contained header**, it "fills in" the triangle cut-out.

[image: The triangle cut out is not possible when there's a full-width colored background block.]

**UPDATE:**

I created a flexbox within a flexbox. Unfortunately, the contained header is not exactly 1200px, and this will be difficult to apply to the overall layout.

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/xVvRmZ

```
.wrapper-whole {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 134px;
  margin: auto;
}
.flexy {
  background: #f00;
  flex: 2;
  height: 134px;
}
.wrapper { /* wraps contained header navbar */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 134px;
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 15px solid #fff;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cutting it out from a background, you could create the illusion of a background by making red elements on each side of the white header using :before and :after pseudo-elements.

In http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyNpdX, I added the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  /* the stuff that was already here */
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after, .wrapper:before{
  content: "";
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 4000px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 134px;
  top: 0;
}
.wrapper:before{
  margin-right: 15px;
  right: 100%;
}
.wrapper:after{
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: yes - you got it! thank you. this is exactly what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions:
 
let me try to answer the ones I've understood. 
I'll keep editing this answer as I go:

1. to **contain** something: you can have the following parent div

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

*this way a child red div, would not appear outside parents constraint.*

2. you can achieve css-**triangles** as:

```css
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

p.s.: you're codepen is so far behind the layout in question, that it's hard to hands-on fix the problem

Comment: hi - i am simply trying to cut out the triangle. i've already cut it out, but when i apply the "red" bg, it covers the triangle. see updated codepen.

Comment: do you mean to have a transparent triangle? use `background: transparent;` or `opacity: 0;`. Also, about the red block. why not have 2, 1 on each side, and free at the middle (so it doesn't cover the triangle). A work around (not sure if it works on windows ie7-), would be to use linear-gradient. hard transitioning from red to transparent to red. 
You can achieve transparent with rgba(255,255,255,0); // last value = opacity.

Comment: Wait. You have a solid white navbar and want to cut-out a triangle? Not possible. What you can do is create an already cut (multiple triangles missing) navbar and cover 3/4 with white, and 1/4 with red. or: 
you can load the background image twice (once inside the triangle, un skew/rotate or whatever transformations you did to the triangle) and position the image with a complex $(window).offset calculation on JavaScript.

Comment: I think I figured it out, but it will be difficult to apply this to entire website layout. http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/xVvRmZ

Answer (score 0):

Place the contained flexbox header, inside of another flexbox.

Place one (red) block on left of header and one (red) block on right.

Create max-width for white header:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper { /* wraps contained header navbar */
    min-width: 1200px;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/xVvdKN

Comment: Glad you got two ways to do it now. :) Just FYI, I'm currently seeing an unexpected gap in FF, in case you weren't aware of it http://i.imgur.com/uTeZxnR.png

Comment: Yes - I'm seeing it too, when I zoom in to 110%. Hmm... :\

Comment: I think I figured it out. The browsers are computing the text height differently. If you explicitly set `.box { line-height: 23px; }`, they appear to work the same (or you can match it to the font-size (20px) and adjust your #test:before and :after top values). (Although that apparently doesn't totally fix the zoom issue, probably since the px values are conflicting with percentages, but I'll let you play around from here.)